# How do I pass validation error from controller to popup form codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I read this question - [Send data from controller to popup...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024419/send-data-from-controller-to-pop-up-modal-using-bootstrap-codeigniter) but not working for me, or perhaps I have not done it well.

I display popup form through a `showpopup($url);` function as shown below

```
<a href="#" onclick="showpopup('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?modal/popup/modal_student_edit/<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>');">
```

I want to send `validation_error();` from controller to the Modal form, but finding it difficult to pass the error to the popup form.

**Controller:**

Form_validation library is auto loaded

```
function student(){
    $verify = array(field, label, rules);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($verify);
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $data['errors'] = validation_errors();

        /** send error to popup form how?
        $this->load->view->(popup_form, $data); **/
    }
}
else{
echo "success";
}
```

**View:**

```
<!-- Display Errors if any -->
    <?php if($errors){?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <?php echo $errors; ?>
        </div>
    <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way in your view:

```
<?php 
$err = validation_errors();
if(isset($err) && !empty($err)):
echo '<script> alert("'.str_replace(array("\r","\n"), '\n', $err).'"); </script>';
endif;
?>
```

or you could do it in your controller itself in this manner:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
  echo '<script> alert("'.str_replace(array("\r","\n"), '\n', validation_errors()).'"); </script>';
  $this->load->view('your_view_name');
}
```

Comment: When I try the code it display blank page with no errors,  but if I assign string value to the '$err'  variable, the alert will display the string,  what could be breaking the code. Perhaps something in 'validation_errors()'  is breaking the script

Comment: did you load the `form_validation` library? if not then add this at the begining of the **student** method: `$this->load->library('form_validation');` @4Jean

Comment: Form validation library is autoloaded in autoload.php

Comment: It finally worked, the problem was the quotes, I had to use single quotes inside script and double quotes outside the `<script>`then it worked  -`$errors = validation_errors();`
`$errors = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "<p>", "</p>"),'\n', $errors);`
 `echo"<script>alert('$errors');</script>";`